# Did the Red Dwarf Season 3 intro steal the crash sound from Empire Strikes back where Luke lands on Degobah?

Tags: star-wars, sound-effects, the-empire-strikes-back, red-dwarf

I was watching the [honest Trailers review of Empire Strikes Back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pg1obK0Qfo), and I heard the crash sound for Luke on Degobah. It made me think of something.

[Here is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYUqXBYA7uM#t=0m49s) Luke's crash on Degobah.

[Here is the intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSxN1souf2U#t=0m3s) to Red Dwarf Season 3 - with a crash sound.

It sounds remarkably similar.

My question is: **Did the Red Dwarf Season 3 intro steal the crash sound from Empire Strikes back where Luke lands on Degobah?**

Comment: I bet that's a sound from a collection of sound effects, e.g. https://www.discogs.com/label/521396-BBC-Sound-Effects .